# How to make a button appear after a button click in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I have this issue here that i want a button (`b1` in code) to appear after the user click in the main button (`b0`).

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter.messagebox
import os

def openword():
    my_program = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    os.system('"%s"' % my_program)

def btn_clicked():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Login","Login Success, Welcome!")

window = Tk()

window.geometry("1000x600")
window.configure(bg = "#293335")
canvas = Canvas(
    window,
    bg = "#293335",
    height = 600,
    width = 1000,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge")
canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)

background_img = PhotoImage(file = f"background.png")
background = canvas.create_image(
    508.5, 228.0,
    image=background_img)

entry0_img = PhotoImage(file = f"img_textBox0.png")
entry0_bg = canvas.create_image(
    166.0, 367.0,
    image = entry0_img)

entry0 = Entry(
    bd = 0,
    bg = "#ffffff",
    highlightthickness = 0)

entry0.place(
    x = 22, y = 351,
    width = 288,
    height = 30)

entry1_img = PhotoImage(file = f"img_textBox1.png")
entry1_bg = canvas.create_image(
    166.0, 456.0,
    image = entry1_img)

entry1 = Entry(
    bd = 0,
    bg = "#ffffff",
    highlightthickness = 0)

entry1.place(
    x = 22, y = 440,
    width = 288,
    height = 30)

img0 = PhotoImage(file = f"img0.png")
b0 = Button(
    image = img0,
    borderwidth = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    command = btn_clicked,
    relief = "flat")

b0.place(
    x = 28, y = 500,
    width = 102,
    height = 38)

img1 = PhotoImage(file = f"img1.png")
b1 = Button(
    image = img1,
    borderwidth = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    command = openword,
    relief = "flat")

b1.place(
    x = 766, y = 505,
    width = 213,
    height = 72)

window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()
```

The code works perfectly but the two buttons appear at the same time.
I need `b1` to appear after the user presss `b0`.

Comment: Please provide a [example]. It's really hard to run your code when there are so many unneeded images in there.

Comment: Then move `b1.place(...)` to inside `btn_clicked()`.

Comment: thanks to @acw1668 i just moved b1.place inside the function and changed somethings and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Like acw1668 is suggesting, place your button inside your function that is called on clicking the other button. Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox

def btn_clicked():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Login","Login Success, Welcome!")
    b2 = tk.Button(
        borderwidth = 0,
        highlightthickness = 0,
        command = btn_clicked,
        relief = "flat"
    )
    b2.place(
        x = 200, y = 200,
        width = 213,
        height = 72
    )

window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry("1000x600")
window.configure(bg = "#293335")

b1 = tk.Button(
    borderwidth = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    command = btn_clicked,
    relief = "flat"
)

b1.place(
    x = 5, y = 5,
    width = 213,
    height = 72
)

window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: don't import everything from a module, import only what you need

Comment: My suggestion is just move the `place(...)` line, not the creation of the button. Your code will create new button whenever the function is executed.

Comment: Thankyou very much, you helped me

Answer (score 0):

You would want to place your button under the `btn_clicked():` function. If you create a button under that function, I'm pretty sure that it creates a new button each time you click.